# Access settings in BuildConfig

Tags: grails, build, config

Is it somehow possible to access the properties specified in `Config.groovy` inside the `BuildConfig.groovy`?

I need to copy some bootstrap files during the packaging process and the target directory depends on the specified environment. Since I need to access those file during application bootstrap I'd like to define the path in the `Config.groovy` and rather not duplicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to access a property such as `bootstrap.path` defined in `Config.groovy` is

```
def bootStrapPath = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder.config.bootstrap.path
```

I've haven't tried this from `BuildConfig.groovy`, but if it doesn't work, then I guess it's because `Config.groovy` hasn't been read when `BuildConfig.groovy` is executed. In that case, you'll need to read it yourself. The implementation of `ConfigurationHolder` should show you how to do this.

Comment: As you mentioned, the `Config.groovy` hasn't been read. I've posted a solution using groovys `ConfigSlurper`. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If when you say the packaging process you mean when generating the WAR file then I've been able to copy files to different places using Grails scripts/events. For example, I needed to copy one file to the WEB-INF/classes folder when generating the WAR so I created an Events.groovy file under the /scripts folder with the following content:

```
// Copy liquibase changelog.xml to classpath folder
eventWarStart = {warName ->
  if (grailsEnv == "production") {
    println "Copying database migration files to classpath!"
    Ant.copy(toFile: "${classesDirPath}/changelog.xml", filtering: true, overwrite: true) {
      fileset(file: "${basedir}/grails-app/migrations/changelog.xml")
    }
    Ant.copy(toDir: "${classesDirPath}/releases/", filtering: true, overwrite: true) {
      fileset(dir: "${basedir}/grails-app/migrations/releases/")
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see in the event you can have access to the environment.

If this is not what you meant, then just ignore my answer.

Comment: +1 for doing it right and not hacking around the build system.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the `grails.war.resources` option to copy files before the WAR is packaged. The problem stays the same with your approach I guess: I somehow need to access an option in the `Events.groovy` script that is defined in `Config.groovy`. Correct me if I'm wrong. @Rob Elsner: What exactly is 'hacking around' in my approach? I'm using the `ConfigSlurper` to gain access to my configurations so I can use them in the `grails.war.resources` closure. Please explain your statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
System.getProperty('grails.env')
```

to retrieve the current environment.

Comment: Thanks but it's not about the environment (this you can also get with `grailsSettings.grailsEnv`). I'm wondering how I can access a property I defined in my `Config.groovy` (like `bootstrap.path=resources/bootstrap`) inside the `BuildConfig.groovy`.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've found was reading the `Config.groovy` by myself (as mentioned by Don). Here my two line solution:

```
def directory = new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path).parent
def config = new ConfigSlurper(grailsSettings.grailsEnv).parse(new File(directory + File.separator + "Config.groovy").toURI().toURL())

println config.bootstrapPath
```