# Grails use config.properties value into BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: grails, properties, groovy, buildconfig

I have a `config.properties` file under `conf` directory.

and have a entry in the above file like this: `grails.tomcat.version = 2.2.4`.

How can I use this value in `BuildConfig.groovy` file?

Suppose:

```
plugins = {
    build ":tomcat:{here i want to use the config value}"
}
```

Comment: see if this link can help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654416/access-settings-in-buildconfig])

Comment: Class ConfigurationHolder is deprecated.

Comment: ConfigurationHolder is replaced by [Holders](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/util/Holders.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do read the `properties` file as below:

```
plugins {
    def props = new Properties()
    new File("grails-app/conf/config.properties").withReader{
        props.load(it)
    }
    def slurp = new ConfigSlurper().parse(props)

    build ":tomcat:$slurp.grails.tomcat.version"
}
```

I do not see a value out of it if you only have that single entry to use from the properties file. I would rather have that config defined in `Config.groovy`.

Comment: Thanks, I have lot of entries to put in that properties file.