# log4 properties injection in grails Config.groovy

Tags: grails, log4j

I would like to inject log4j config stuff stored in a properties file in my Config.groovy.

Here is my properties file :

```
log.file=path/to/my/log
log.root.level=info
log.grails.app.level=info
```

No problem for file path EL syntax ${} but it doesn't work for levels as it is not strings. Here is the config.groovy :

```
appenders {
    file name:'file', file:"${config.log.file}"
}

root {
    ${log.root.level} 'stdout', 'file'
}
```

Any advise ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the properties file and convert it to a ConfigObject to use in Config.groovy.

```
log4j {
    def props = new Properties()
    new File("path/to/log.properties").withReader{
        props.load(it)
    }
    def slurp = new ConfigSlurper().parse(props)

    appenders {
        file name:'file', file:"$slurp.log.file"
    }

    root {
        "$slurp.log.root.level" 'stdout', 'file'
    }
}
```

Refer this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885509/grails-use-config-properties-value-into-buildconfig-groovy/18886080#18886080).

Comment: Thanks, I am now able to load my properties but when server is starting I have a **Exception occured configuring log4j logging: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.level() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [stdout, file]**

Comment: My bad. Missed the quotes.Updated answer.

Comment: It works, thanks. I didn't understood exactly the double quotes trilck, I am quite new to Groovy/Grails world...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the code of the Grails [Log4J DSL parser](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-log4j/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/log4j/Log4jConfig.groovy) correctly you should just be able to say

```
root {
    "${config.config.log.root.level}" 'stdout', 'file'
}
```

or if that doesn't work then

```
root {
    delegate."${config.config.log.root.level}" 'stdout', 'file'
}
```

Normally, within the `log4j` closure you have access to the complete `grailsApplication.config` (including options merged in from external configuration files) as the variable `config` but it looks like you need a second `config` in front of that when you're inside the `root {}` block.

<sup>Explanation - the closure delegate of the `root` closure is a `RootLog4jConfig` object, which has a property `config` pointing to the main `Log4jConfig` which is the delegate for the rest of the `log4j` closure, and that in turn has its own property `config` pointing to the parsed `ConfigObject`.  I somehow doubt that this behaviour is deliberate, and it might be worth a JIRA to suggest that `config` should resolve to the same thing inside the `root` block as outside it.</sup>

Comment: I have tried the both solutions. No output logs and this message on server startup **log4j:ERROR Property missing when configuring log4j: log**

Comment: @LaurentBOURGEOIS for the `config.` things to work you'll have to list the external properties file in `grails.config.locations`

Comment: properties file is already in my config.locations `def envName = System.properties.getProperty("tomcat.server.name")
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:"+envName+"-config.properties"]`

Comment: @LaurentBOURGEOIS hmm, inspecting [the code](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-log4j/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/log4j/Log4jConfig.groovy) it looks like `config.config.log.root.level` might work --you need an extra "config" inside the root closure compared to outside it. I doubt this is intentional...