# How to access config properties in BuildConfig for grails 2.3.2

Tags: grails

I am trying to set a dependency version from a config.grooy properties. I have found a supoused way to do it here: [pritomkumar.blogspot](https://pritomkumar.blogspot.com.es/2013/09/grails-access-configgroovy-settings-in.html). This is the proposed solution:

> Include the following lines in 'BuildConfig.groovy' file

```
def directory = new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path).parent;
def config = new ConfigSlurper(grailsSettings.grailsEnv).parse(new File(directory + File.separator + "Config.groovy").toURI().toURL())
println "| Tomcat Version (API): " + config.grails.tomcat.version;
....    
plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:2.2.4"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.2"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

    build ":tomcat:"+config.grails.tomcat.version

    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

    compile ':cache:1.0.1'
}
```

> Include the following lines in 'Config.groovy'

```
grails.tomcat.version = "2.2.4"
```

but It looks to work for older grails version, because I got this **error** when I try to refresh-dependecies:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
script15010760392501179421923.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.whatever.configuration.ConfigurationFilesManager
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import com.whatever.configuration.ConfigurationFilesManager
   ^

1 error

    at BuildConfig.run(BuildConfig.groovy:17)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1087)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1073)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$loadConfig$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1053)
```

| Error There was an error loading the BuildConfig: startup failed:
script15010760392501179421923.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.whatever.configuration.ConfigurationFilesManager
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import com.whatever.configuration.ConfigurationFilesManager

Any Help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may check
[Grails use config.properties value into BuildConfig.groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885509/grails-use-config-properties-value-into-buildconfig-groovy)

Just replace config.properties to config.goorvy
then you can get the Config value in BuildConfig
tested in 2.5.6

But if we define a config in config.groovy such as 
`tomcatVersion = "2.2.4"

build ":tomcat:$slurp.tomcatVersion" will turn into ":tomcat:**"2.2.4"**"
it's not fit the format

you can use another expression like
`compile group: 'org.grails', name: 'tomcat', version: $slurp.tomcatVersion`